# how to open an angular xeditable input automatically without editable-form

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, x-editable

I'm using a angular [xeditable](http://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/#text-simple) text control. I want to open it in edit mode automatically. How can I do it?

My question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25988154/how-to-make-angular-xeditable-edit-state-always-enabled) however, I am not using [editable-form](http://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/#editable-form) (not using a form element at all). The only solutions I find are using the editable-form's **$show()** function, but you do not have it if you do not have an editable-form.

While at it, I also would like to use the functionality provided by editable-form's **$setError()** function, without using an editable-form and not through the *onbeforesave* or *onaftersave* attributes (I want to do it upon opening the xeditable text control, not when user submits). Is it possible ?

I do not want to use an editable-form because I have just this one xeditable input, and the use of a form changes things like submit, blur, buttons displayed, etc. in ways that I do not want.

Comment: Can you show the code?

Comment: Sure:

`<div class="xedit ng-scope"><span e-name="titleCtrl" editable-text="book.title" e-label="Title" onbeforesave="checkTitle($data)">
    {{ book.title || 'title' }}
</span></div>`

So the question is how to open that xeditable text input programmatically (e.g. using ng-init) without the user having to click on it first. The input is not inside an editable-form, so I cannot use $show().

Comment: I just want to confirm if this is the behaviour you want. [look at this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/rdBPsibOFwLhzaCsQqJ3)

Comment: That looks good indeed. So the trick is simply to put an `<input>` element in the HTML, which xeditable turns into an `<a>` element on submit ? How does it decide to make it an `<a>` element and not (for example) a `<span>` element, can you control that ?

Comment: In my example I don't use the xeditable. It is raw angularjs. you can use <span> or other desired element you want! if you need explaination I will add comment for you to understand!

Comment: Did you find a solution ? I have the exact same question...